# rails: attempting to match two values in an array, getting Unsupported argument type: Hash error

Tags: database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, arel, ruby-hash

I have two fields in two different models which store location values in an array and what I am trying to achieve is a controller instance variable that can match any identical values in both arrays and then show that in the index view. However, when I try this code

```
@submissions = Submission.select(Desired_Location: current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
```

its throws this error:

```
Unsupported argument type: Hash. Construct an Arel node instead
```

Submission Schema:

```
create_table "submissions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "First_Name"
t.string "Last_Name"
t.integer "Phone"
t.string "Email"
t.string "Desired_Location"
t.integer "number_of_beds"
t.integer "number_of_occupants"
t.integer "Rent_price_per_month_gbp"
t.date "Max_move_in_date"
t.string "Tenant_Occupation"
t.string "Contact_me_on"
t.boolean "Furnished"
t.string "Current_Address"
t.text "Property_Requirements"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "location_id"
t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_submissions_on_location_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_submissions_on_user_id"
 end
```

Agent Schema:

```
create_table "agents", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "Company_Name"
t.string "Company_Email"
t.string "Company_Phone"
t.string "Company_Address"
t.string "Company_Business_Location"
t.string "Contact_Name"
t.string "Contact_Email"
t.string "Contact_Phone"
t.integer "location_id"
t.index ["email"], name: "index_agents_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_agents_on_location_id"
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: 
"index_agents_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
 end
```

Sample of how data is stored in both Desired_Location and Company_Business_Location fields:

```
["", "Abbey Wood", "Acton", "Anerley", "Angel"]
```

Comment: column name of table must be in small letters always -> `Desired_Location`

Answer (score 0):

If Desired_Location is the field name in the Submission model then use the select method as below. Select method won't accept a hash as an argument.

You can pass a block to check the condition and get the desired result. Used sort on the array to make the array identical if it's positioned differently in spite of containing all the elements.

```
desired_loc_arr = current_agent.Company_Business_Location
@submissions = Submission.select { |sub| sub.Desired_Location.sort == desired_loc_arr.sort }
```

Comment: This does not work for me, its throwing the following error: 'select' with block doesn't take arguments.

Comment: Calculated the desired_loc_arr before creating the instance variable. updated the answer, I think now it will work.

Comment: Sorry this isn't working either, still getting the same error

Comment: can I get the field names of both the models and any sample data of how values are stored in the fields?

Comment: Hi mate, sure thing I have added that to the orginal post. Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

To match with identical values of an array in rails query,
you can use `ANY of postgres` in rails

```
Submission.where(? = ANY(Desired_Location)", current_agent.Compay_Business_Location)
```

Read more here http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-any/